# obtain a relation between $I_n$ and $I_{n−1}$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

If, for any integer n > 1,

$$ I_n = \int_{1}^{e} x(\ln x)^ndx$$

obtain a relation between $I_n$ and $I_{n−1}$

I am unsure on how to start this question.
Thank you

Comment: *"I am unsure on how to start this question."* - Have you tried to simplify $I_{n+1}$ and find similarity to $I_n$? Maybe partial fraction or some substitution helps?

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}I_n&=\int_1^ex(\ln x)^n\,\mathrm dx\\&=\left.\frac{x^2}2(\ln x)^n\right|_{x=1}^{x=e}-\int_1^e\frac{x^2}2n\frac1x(\ln x)^{n-1}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\frac{e^2}2-\frac n2I_{n-1}.\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

$$I_n = \int_1^e x(\ln(x))^n \ dx = \frac{x^2}{2}(\ln(x))^n\biggm|_1^e -\int_1^e \frac{x^2}{2} \cdot \frac{n (\ln(x))^{n-1}}{x} \ dx$$
$$ = \frac{e^2}{2} - \frac{n}{2}\int_1^e x(\ln(x))^{n-1}\ dx$$
$$= \frac{e^2}{2} - \frac{n}{2}I_{n-1}.$$

We used integration by parts for the first equality.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use the substitution $y=\log x$

Integral $I_n$ then becomes

$$I_n=\int_0^1 y^n e^{2y}dy$$

and on integrating by parts we get

$$\int_0^1 y^n e^{2y}dy=\left[\frac{y^n e^{2y}}{2} \right]_0^1-\frac{n}{2} \int_0^1 y^{n-1} e^{2y} dy$$

with the result $$I_n=\frac{e^2}{2}-\frac{n}{2}I_{n-1}$$